# Selecting only columns which names are stored in another table

Tags: postgresql

I have table which has many columns and I want to select just some of them - but I want to select columns which names are stored in another table(don't ask me why like this, I'm just trying to get something from existing system).

My table with data:

```
Table 1

id | username | age | height | hobby | weight | eye_color
1  |                 ... some users data...
2  |                 ... some users data...
3  |                 ... some users data...
```

And another table with column names from `Table 1` which I want to select

```
Table 2
id | columnname
1  | username
2  | height
3  | weight
```

so after all sql should do something like this:

```
select
  t.username,
  t.height,
  t.weight
from Table1 t
```

If I change something in Table 2 - then select sql also should be changed

How can I do it in PgSQL?

Comment: Why don't you create a view that only returns the columns you want?

Comment: Assign the fields names to a variable with: `select array_agg(columnname) from columnlist`. Then do something like `SELECT format ('select %s from table1', fn);`